# How Do I access Data in Facebook Array with PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have made a simple facebook register widget.

On register the App sends the data to send.php

On send.php I have

```
  print_r($response);
```

And I get something like this:

```
Array
(
    [algorithm] => HMAC-SHA256
    [expires] => 1367953200
    [issued_at] => 1367946138
    [oauth_token] => BAAE0refKufgBAORkK7hUaVpF8MnFygoqHAHrO3nRJMyNjvJx6RjiMjoqbz2YlfqeogcIPGJJaIgD0xtxhBj1WRgQ5F5SidjwM7ZCKOyZBlEuatIqIccbjGj2uMV5hqtKtZA1g7hOEqMeZAEwmnO6SgRgsb9ittKZCDnPfoxYxCxZAZBAhIKX457IG5ZB4yknv9FZB8QUG7Pt0mfBRQUYG12KoTmO7QRH20LP65FyPqTi7mAZDZD
    [registration] => Array
        (
            [name] => derp derp
            [email] => ddddd@gmail.com
            [location] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Vienna, Austria
                    [id] => 1.1116511224109E+14
                )

            [gender] => male
            [phone] => sss
        )

    [registration_metadata] => Array
        (
            [fields] => [ {'name':'name'}, {'name':'email'}, {'name':'location'}, {'name':'gender'}, {'name':'phone',      'description':'Phone Number',             'type':'text'},]
        )

    [user] => Array
        (
            [country] => at
            [locale] => en_US
        )

    [user_id] => 100000506481284
)
```

So the data gets passed without a problem but how can I access a specific value?

For example text book array stuff doesnt appear to be working like:

```
print $response[0];
```

Gives me an error:

```
Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\ddd\send.php on line 38
```

How else can I access the data?

For example how could I store country, email, name or whatever in their own variables so I can echo them later? Its there but I cant seem to figure out how to "digest" it properly with php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no index 0 in the array you pasted..

Use it like

```
$email = $response['registration']['email'];
```

If it was an object instead of an array you would do

```
$email = $response->registration->email
```

This is very basic PHP array handling.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php